# Overlap the layout in the android ExpandableListView

Tags: expandablelistview

In the following template , at the above New vhd text,
overlap the row , I want to fix this problem .I tried to change the height of the Main File but no used.I just increase the text Size 14 to 15 PX in the all template ,size increased in main template programmatically, this problem occur. I attached my code with the question also see the  commented section in XML file.Please suggest me solution if any.I am new to android .Not familiar with the android.I also attached the image below.Thank you.

//Main file

```
                                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <LinearLayout
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                         android:orientation="vertical"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"  //Changed the height but not work 
                         android:background="#ffffff">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="35dp" 
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:background="@color/green">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/queue_header"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:text="Inbox"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                      </LinearLayout>



                    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/que_list"
                               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"  //changed as fill_parent but not worked
                               android:groupIndicator="@drawable/settings_selector"/>

                </LinearLayout>
```

//Second File

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> //changed as fill_parent but not worked

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
                         android:paddingLeft="50px"
                         android:paddingTop="10px"//changed as 15px not worked
                         android:paddingBottom="10px"//changed as 15px not worked
                         android:textSize="15px"
                         android:textColor="#0b730b"
                         android:layout_width="250px"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>//changed as fill_parent but not worked
                </LinearLayout>
```

//Third file

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">//changed as fill_parent but not worked

                     <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:paddingLeft="40px" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/green" /> 

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
                         android:paddingLeft="20px"
                         android:paddingTop="10px"
                         android:paddingBottom="10px"
                         android:textSize="15px"
                         android:textColor="#0b730b"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/child_id"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                       <TextView android:id="@+id/dept_id"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/rgb"
                         android:textSize="16px"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
                         android:textColor="#0b730b"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>
```